# bash > prohibit to use redirection (>)

Tags: bash

My environments:

```
CentOS 6.5
bash 4.1.2(1)
```

Sometimes when I intend to add something to a file,
instead of

```
$ echo "xxx" >> mymemo.txt
```

I type mistakenly

```
$ echo "xxx" > mymemo.txt
```

resulting in loosing memos in `mymemo.txt`.

I am wondering if there is a way to prohibit to use redirection (>), but allow to use redirection (>>)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `set -o noclobber` in your `.bashrc` or `.profile`

If set, bash prevents you from overwriting existing files when redirecting.

```
mint@mint ~ $ echo "foo" > test
bash: test: cannot overwrite existing file
```